# Como quito las lineas de un menu en python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Quisiera saber si se pueden sacar estas lineas, busque en google y no encontré como quitarlas, no se si se pueda.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi codigo:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

ventana = tk.Tk()

menu = Menu(ventana)
menuLista = Menu(menu)
menuLista.add_command(label="Opciones")
menu.add_cascade(label="Lista",menu=menuLista)

ventana.config(menu=menu)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Para que no te aparezcan esas lineas segmentadas debes mandar el
>   parámetro `tearoff` con un **valor 0**, así de esta forma des
>   habilitas esa opción por defecto:

```
menuLista = Menu(menu, tearoff =0)
```